# Drop-down-menu not working on second page

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

I have to make a website for school and we have to make a drop-down-menu. I've made one and it works fine, but on my other pages the drop-down-menu won't open when I click on it.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: At least show us what you did

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you use the chrome developer tools to check and see what happens to the other pages when you click the button that's supposed to initiate the dropdown menu.

If nothing happens, right click the button and hit **inspect** in developer tools to verify that you're targeting the correct element, and to verify that the dropdown menu actually exists on all your pages.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you haven't linked the javascript file on the other pages. Can't say much without you showing what you've done first.